# ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays LSTM Keras

Tags: keras, lstm

Here is the part for data preparing - I just want the data to be in the correct shape

```
x_train , x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(input_data, y , test_size = 0.2 , random_state = 33)
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
```

> (200, 3)
>
> (200, 1)

```
#Converting them into numpy arrays 
input_x_train = x_train.as_matrix()
input_y_train = y_train.as_matrix()
print(input_x_train.shape)
print(input_y_train.shape)
```

> (200, 3)
>
> (200, 1)

```
input_x_test = x_test.as_matrix()
input_y_test = y_test.as_matrix()
print(input_x_test.shape)
print(input_y_test.shape)
```

> (51, 3)
>
> (51, 1)

```
#Reshaping into LSTM input format 
input_x = input_x_train.reshape((1, input_x_train.shape[0], input_x_train.shape[1]))
print(input_x.shape)
```

> (1, 200, 3)

Then I built my model like this:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM 
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(200, 3)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(input_x, input_y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=16)
```

But I am getting this error

> ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as
>   target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 200 target samples.

Comment: Is your dataset 251 samples, each with 3 features?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat yes

Answer (score 0):

The `input_shape` parameter should not include your batch size. Given that each sample of yours dataset has three features, you should set `input_shape=(3,)`.

In addition, you should not reshape your batch to `(1, batch_size, 3)`. I'm not sure why you're doing that, but as far as I can tell that will break things. Remove that line entirely.

Comment: But this is an LSTM, the input has to include the following: Samples, Time Steps, and features. Doing as you said did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Wanderer The shape of your input data is `(200, 3)`. Is this 1 sample with 200 timesteps and 3 features? Or is it 200 independent samples, each with 3 timesteps and 1 feature?